# How to find the device screen height and width programmatically for android version 4.0 above and below?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am having a image in drawable **res** folder .I need to set the two image centre vertically below.

I don't need to use the xml to set image view to:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

because the image pixels get damaged.

My app seems to be doing so much work in the ui thread and facing a memory leaks.

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: your question is a little unclear. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to get screen size in inch

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
int dens=dm.densityDpi;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dens;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dens;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution .

Comment: @pradeep Your Welcome , hit the vote Up :)